# Searching for a-really-long-search-term pushes "Cancel" off the screen

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, ios-app

Steps to reproduce;

1. Pull down the screen on the question-listing page to open the search bar.
2. Type is "this is a really really really long search term"
3. Hit enter to submit the search query
4. Note how there is no top-bar, and the "Cancel" button which is normally next to the search box has disappeared.

   > [image]

   ... as opposed to the normal view of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUuO9.jpg). This leaves you unable to exit the search view, short of editing your search input to remove a few terms, such that the "Cancel" button slides back into view.

Comment: I was trying to reproduce in my pc but can't then I noticed that ios-app tag.

Comment: @hims056 didn't you notice the odd design in the screenshot?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Grace period...

Comment: @Matt thanks for the great bug report, I'm looking into this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This has been fixed.** Fix should be available in version 0.1.20.